# Getting an empty space when trying to use gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

So I followed the tutorial and screencast but can't seem to get this to work. I can see the div id's called map container and gmaps4rails_map where presumably, the map is supposed to be but nothing else.

I put in the yield `:head` and yield `:script` in the header and footer of the application layout view and `@charger = Charger.all.to_gmaps4rails` (Charger is my model) in the chargers_helper.html.erb file (I want to use in User show view).

I also put `<%= gmaps4rails(@charger) %>` in the show.html.erb view.

How do I get this to work?

-Update-

I just got it to work. To fix the problem I put in the @charger = ... code in a method in the helper and called the method instead of @charger.

Now the map shows up but I still cannot see the insert new marker code like in the screencast - I don't need it for my app but am curious as to what happened to it.

Comment: If the div is in the document but is empty then the problem is with the javascript code you are executing. Can you post the code that retrieves the maps? Also, have you seen any Javascript errors in Firebug or something similar? (And if you are not using Firebug to debug javascript then you really should)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Just curious though: why donyou lut methods in helper instead of controller?

Answer (score 0):

In the screencast, I create model + controller with a scaffold generator. That's why I have ready to use links.

Besides, I create buttons during the screencast. Nothing is made behind the scene: the whole app is created from scratch :)